# What Entities Are Using This Site for Their Q&A

Tags: discussion

I was told in one question that healthcare.gov is directing their q&a here.
To that I have two questions:
a) What groups are doing this?
b) How much of this is just them dumping the job here and not doing their job themselves?

b can be seen as a negative, but I don't mean it that way; I've noticed alot of questions regarding healthcare/finder/api that go unanswered.
I would think that they would be watching and responding, but I don't see that happening.

really curious to how/what is going on here.

Comment: [Is asking questions about a particular data set on-topic?](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/333/1652)

Comment: i think so but i don't know for sure. all the ones that come through review and are flagged in such manner, i typically keep open.